# C# and XNA is possible switch beetween Game classes?

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, game-engine

I'm working on a small game application for *Windows Phone 8*.

I've three games inside and I want to know if it's possible to switch (from the main.cs) from game1 to game2 to game3 in a rando time.

I'm going to explain it a little
Here's the tree of the application

- Resources
- References
- Classes

  - AbstractGame.cs
  - Pong.cs
  - Arkanoid.cs
- List item
- Main.cs
- Program.cs

Basically the purpose of the game is that, you set a random numer in the main.cs and then the main switch between pong and arkanoid (and you have to be prepare for the change)

The abstract is only a "container" that inherits Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

It "works" well until I run the program on the debugger because it shows me this error.

"Cannot running multiple istance of Game"

This is caused because Main.cs, Pong.cs and Arkanoid.cs are Game-child class

Is there any solution to this? I mean, it's possible to avoid that kind of error with this logic (running/switching game in Main.cs)

It's better if Pong.cs and Arkanoid inherits from DrawableGameComponent?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is with Game Components, like you had mentioned in your question.

Then it would be simply a matter of adding all your game components to your main Game object:

```
Game.Components.Add(myGameComponent);
```

And then set the Enable flag accordingly.

```
myGameComponent.Enabled = true;
```

Then it is simply a matter of looping through your game components, and updating/drawing the ones that are enabled.

Comment: Cool I'm going to try it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'd be better off if each of your mini-games derive from DrawableGameComponent.